# SPRING JPA REPOSITORY: entity not reflecting in database

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Trying to save my entity in database using JPA save() call but didn't get any record in database in database after call completion.

While debug, I'm getting auto generated Id in returned entity but same is not reflecting in database.

I Marked my repository as @Transaction .
Using default JPA save() api.
Not getting any exception while saving entity.

```
Repository:
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true)
public interface SampleRepository extends CrudRepository

Entity:
@Entity
@Table(name = "SAMPLE")
public class SAMPLE {
```

Comment: Could you provide the code from your controller, where you call your `save()`

Comment: Please provide the code and database configuration done in application.properties

Comment: Here is the save call:
sampleRepository.save(sample);

Other entities are saving properly with existing db configuration properties